# Retrieve data from DataTable plugin using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using DataTable plugin for generating data from database using javascript. I am showing that data in table tag like

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
                                        $total += $row->price;
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->created_date; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->vender; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->usertype; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->price; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->payment_type; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->vender_inv; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->note; ?></td>
                                            <td><a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" data-lightbox="example-1"><img style="width:100px !important; height:100px !important;" class="example-image" src="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" alt="image-1" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <?php
                                    }
```

Now I want to retrieve individual rows from it, I am trying to do it like this

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
        table.column(4).eq(0).each( function ( colIdx ) {
            console.log( colIdx, table.column( colIdx ).search() );
        } );
```

Comment: Retrieve in the scene do you want to read table row values on some event??

Comment: Yes when search applied on datatable i want to save the result of rows that match with search basically i have a coulmn price and i want to calculate the sum of price and display it..  let suppose 3 result match out of 50 i just want to add price of those results and display ..

Answer (score 0):

Look at the rows() API:  https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()

```
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    var data = this.data();
    // ... do something with data(), or this.node(), etc
} );
```